# Need help on grouping this SQL table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this table

[image]

I want to group it like

```
ProductID       Purchased      Sold
------------------------------------
1               235            0.00
2               125            0.00
3               55             24.00
```

Here Purchased = (IsCreditor <> 0)

I tried this

```
SELECT
    ProductID, 
    Max (TotalQty) As Purchased,
    Min(TotalQty) As Sold
FROM
    TestTable
GROUP BY
    ProductID
```

It will work only if a product have both IsCreditor = 0 and IsCreditor = 1

The table is a small part of a stored Procedure

In this table, for productid = 1, if it is not purchased or sold, it won't appear and if it is purchased it appears with a qty and IsCreditor = 1 and if it is sold, it appears with qty in one row with IsCreditor=0 and one more with isCreditor=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add a CASE statement to separate purchased and sold items

```
    SELECT
        ProductID, 
        SUM(Case When IsCreditor = 1 then TotalQty else 0 end) AS [TotalPurchase],
        SUM(Case When IsCreditor = 0 then TotalQty else 0 end) AS [TotalSale]
    FROM
        TestTable
    GROUP BY
        ProductID
```